# Adding css classes to taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to have all my taxonomy terms to look different from each other.

Is there  a way for me add specific CSS classes to differing taxonomy terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add class to taxnonomy term in view](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152629/add-class-to-taxnonomy-term-in-view)

Comment: where you want this class added ? in views? node? where?

Answer (score 1):

Already the **page-taxonomy-term-TERM_ID** is present on the body tag.

To add more classes you can use `hook_preprocess_html()` and add the `$vars['classes_array']` to add the css classes you want for the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about taxonomy pages? If so you can target each one of them with the default body class "page-taxonomy-term-X" where X is the taxonomy id.

If you want a different class, I suggest you to use the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context)

Answer (score 0):

If you want add class to term in everywhere I suggest customize taxonomy template with  [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7.x).
This will allow you to customize the output of your term page.

also if you want to  add class to it in views result
use  [Field Formatter CSS Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) module is what you're looking for.

> Adds a formatter for text/list/taxonomy fields to render as CSS classes on nodes.
>
> The Field formatter CSS class module allows you to set any text/list/option/taxonomy field to render as CSS class on the node. This enables the node author to select predefined CSS styling per node.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new filed

admin/structure/taxonomy/{vocabulary}/fields

then use this filed with custom template

using normal theme suggestions and overwrites or

**Note** this code related to another issue [*How to render node using custom view mode*]

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().
  add new view info [name , label]
 */
function {ModuleName}_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['node']['view modes']['{ViewName}'] = array(
    'label' => t('{ViewName Label}'),
    'custom settings' => TRUE,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
  register templates path so drupal could find this view name template 
  and you could add this template inside your module
 */
function {ModuleName}_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    // Defined path to the current module.
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', '{ModuleName}');
  // Find all .tpl.php files in this module's folder recursively.
  $template_file_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $module_path);
  // Iterate through all found template file objects.
  foreach ($template_file_objects as $key => $template_file_object) {
      // If the template has not already been overridden by a theme.
      if (!isset($theme_registry[$key]['theme path']) || !preg_match('#/themes/#', $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'])) {
          // Alter the theme path and template elements.
          $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'] = $module_path;
          $theme_registry[$key] = array_merge($theme_registry[$key], $template_file_object);
          $theme_registry[$key]['type'] = 'module';
      }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
  use our custom view as theme suggestions while rendering this a node who use this view mode
 */
function {ModuleName}_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if($variables['view_mode'] == '{ViewName}') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $variables['type'] . '__{ViewName}';
  }
}
```